# Can Process Builder get the ID of a row it just created?

Tags: process-builder

If a Process Builder flow (note, not a Visual Flow) creates a record, can it return or retrieve that row ID or Name in the same flow? 
So a subsequent action in the same flow can log something like 'PB flow ABC created Account row XYZ' ?

Comment: ofcourse Yes,  the question would be, how would you identify which record was created?

Comment: So do you have a suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: How are you creating the record? Are you using a quick create or similar that's assigned to a variable name? Once created, if assigned to a variable name, just as with apex, that variable will now have an Id assigned to it if the variable is an object.

Comment: I am creating the record with a 'Process Builder' flow as per my question's title, not by a 'Visual Flow' flow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. But it's painful. I have done it for clients using professional edition.

You create a lookup on the second object. For example, let's say an account was to create a contract and then update a contract field on the account.

1. Create a account lookup on the contact called related account.
2. Create the first process builder which creates the contact, and populate this lookup field.
3. Create a second process builder that fires when this account lookup is populated. In that process builder you can update the original account, saving the id of the new contact somewhere.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it can do so, just like apex - no lookup required.

I created a simple flow to create a task using a `fast create`.

After creating the task, I added a screen, and displayed the task ID.

It worked as is - no lookup was needed to get the task ID after creating it.

I also tested w/ an old-fashioned `record create` element, and it worked fine, as long as you assign the ID to a variable using the option presented in the record create dialog.

**Flow:**

[image: screenshot of flow]

**Screen with Task ID:**

[image: taskid]

**Record Create Assign ID to Variable:**

[image: assign ID to variable]

Comment: gorav, I am NOT talking abaout a Visual Flow flow which is what you have presented, rather I am talking about a 'Process Builder' flow.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification I saw the word flow in the question and went from there.  Will ponder.